# Error "Invalid Session Handle or Empty Buffer" on resetting watchdog using ipmiutil.exe

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, ipmitool

I'm using ipmiutil.exe to reset the IPMI watchdog on my 64-bit Supermicro server (X11SBA-F) running Windows 10 Enterprise IOT, but it's not working returning the following error:

```
ipmiutil wdt -r
ipmiutil wdt ver 3.13
-- BMC version 1.53, IPMI version 2.0
wdt data: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Watchdog timer is stopped for use with reserved. Logging
               pretimeout is 0 seconds, pre-action is None
               timeout is 0 seconds, counter is 0 seconds
               action is No action
Resetting watchdog timer ...
reset_wdt: ret = 128
wdt data: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Watchdog timer is stopped for use with reserved. Logging
               pretimeout is 0 seconds, pre-action is None
               timeout is 0 seconds, counter is 0 seconds
               action is No action

ipmiutil wdt, Invalid Session Handle or Empty Buffer
```

I installed Intel IMB Driver downloaded from this [link](http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/kern/imbdrv130.zip) and tried both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of ipmiutil.exe but to no avail.  Has anyone faced a similar error?

UPDATE 1:

I tried disabling Windows IPMI driver ipmidrv.sys but it don't help.  On further tests, I noticed that after enabling IPMI watchdog through BIOS, it still shows "Watchdog timer is stopped for use with reserved." when I issue "ipmiutil wdt".  It appears that ipmituil is unable to obtain the correct setting on the watchdog.

Here's some more information:

```
ipmiutil health
ipmiutil health ver 3.13
BMC manufacturer  = 002a7c (SuperMicro), product = 0891
BMC version       = 1.53, IPMI v2.0
BIOS Version      = 1.1a
IPMI driver type  = 1        (imb)
Power State       = 00       (S0: working)
Selftest status   = 0055     (OK)
Chassis Status    = 21 00 40 00 (on, see below)
        chassis_power       = on
        pwr_restore_policy  = last_state
        chassis_intrusion   = inactive
        front_panel_lockout = inactive
        drive_fault         = false
        cooling_fan_fault   = false
Power On Hours    = 18 hours (0 days)
BMC LAN Channels  = 1
ipmiutil health, completed successfully
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  The problem had nothing to do with intel imb driver or 32bit/64bit.  Enabling watchdog in bios is not sufficient.  I had to enable it using ipmiutil:

```
ipmiutil wdt -e
```